# Moving Camera to GameObject: The targetposition is wrong after rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to place the camera in front of a GameObject onTrigger. It works with my code as long as the GameObject faces one particular direction, but if I rotate it, the target position will be behind the GameObject.
What do I miss? :)

```
        mainCamera.transform.position = currentGameObject.transform.position + new Vector3(lookingDistance, 0, 0);
        mainCamera.transform.LookAt(currentGameObject.transform);
```

The script is not attached to the GOs. I use kind of an interactionManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rotation code seems all right, but when finding new position you do not take rotation into account.
Try changing

```
 + new Vector3(lookingDistance, 0, 0);
```

into

```
 + currentGameObject.transform.TransformPoint(new Vector3(lookingDistance, 0, 0));
```